# Data recovery after conversion from MBR to GPT

Tags: ntfs, gpt

I have following situation: by accident I run **diskpart clean**, **then convert to GPT against NTFS MBR disk to which I previously backed up all my data**... No other actions were performed with this disk so far.
Can you advice me something about chances of successful data restore and best way to restore my data in such situation?

Comment: No-one can ell you about your chances of success, you'll just have to try with a few good data recovery programs and hope for the best. Just remember to recover data to a *different* physical drive altogether.

Comment: @Karan: I am sorry. I messed up with two different questions. Let's delete our comments, so people don't get confused anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I would give a try to `testdisk` utility.

It can scan your disk, find your filesystems and based on that information rebuild partition table. 
Use some live cd or just Ubuntu install disk and if you can first backup image of your drive:

> sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/media/myotherdrive/sda-backup.dd

or at least beginning of your disk:

> sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/media/myotherdrive/sda-backup.dd bs=1M count=10

Good luck.

P.S. read carefully all warnings from testdisk and think twice before you run `dd` command.

Comment: Thanks to all for advice. I end up using GetDataBack for NTFS and was able to restore 99% of my data. Had only one minor issue in process - russian folder/file names were displaye incorrectly until I set Russian as a language for non-unicode programs.

Answer (score 1):

Though I already written this in comments I want to post what worked for me - I used [GetDataBack for NTFS](https://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-products.htm) and not only was able to restore 99% of my data but also was able to done it quickly. I tried some other utilities back at the time - they tried to scan my drive for a very long time with poor results or no results at all.
I think as in my case no data was overwritten on top of what I had and only partition information was modified GetDataBack happened to be very good solution which helped me. But this is not a free software (current price tag 79$) and I am not sure if free equivalents exist (I hope they do).